# Apex batch Job problem

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to move records from one custom Object(Course_temp__c) to another custom Object(Course__c) using Apex batch. This is the code I have:

```
global class MyBatchJob2 implements Database.Batchable<Course_temp__c> {

global MyBatchJob2(){}

global List<Course_temp__c> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return [Select Id, Name, Contact__c, Course_Fees__c,Date__c From Course_temp__c];
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Course_temp__c> scope) {
   List<Course__c> lhList = new List<Course__c>();
   for(Course_temp__c obj : scope){
       System.debug('Course_temp records are: ' +obj);
       lhList.add(
           new Course__c(
              Name = obj.Name,
               Contact__c = obj.Contact__c,
               Course_Fees__c = obj.Course_Fees__c,
               Date__c = obj.Date__c
           )
       );
       System.debug('The list is: '+lhlist);
   }
   insert lhList;
   delete scope;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    System.debug('Finished Succesfully');
}}
```

I am invoking the batch class using    `Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new MyBatchJob2(), 200);`

The code is running without any compilation errors and I also get the 'Finished Successfully' message in the debug log. However, the records are not moving from Course_temp__c to Course__c. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions guys, the code is working now. I commented out the constructor and delete scope from the code I posted above, and it's somehow working. I know these might not be the real reason why the code wasn't working before, but I don't know what else is different now. Thanks again, I  really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as accepted so the question no longer shows as open?